# Youtrack level of integration with GIT (not github)

Tags: git, teamcity, agile, youtrack

I have tried to find information on this but its all small amounts of information which seem to contradict or discuss older versions of the features available in Youtrack.

From my understanding you need Teamcity set up and linked to YouTrack so it knows to parse the commit messages. However I am wondering at what level it integrates with YouTrack, as the current information:

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD3/Integration+with+TeamCity

There doesn't seem to be a relevant 4.X version, but it implies that you can commit with a hashtag and it will carry out some actions based upon your commit message, like the one below:

```
#PR-1 Fixed
Have fixed the underlying issue for this bug, it was due to X,Y,Z
```

In my eyes that would set `#PR-1` to state fixed, however the documentation in the link above seems to imply that comments are not carried over, which seems a bit rubbish. So is there a way from YouTrack to get the relevant information as to what was done in that commit? be it through a link that takes you through to TeamCity to see the commit message or alternative method.

We were originally using TFS but it is painful to develop with because of its horrible read only flags which stops templating of files in build scripts, the workflow editor for building and testing software and finally the work item tracker which is great for everyone who uses Visual Studio, if you don't you get a rubbish web front end.

Anyway... I was under the impression that Youtrack, TeamCity, Git could all be used together end to end and you can have complete traceability linking the commit that was put into GIT with the release built by TeamCity and the story put into the completion state in YouTrack.

So assuming you have GIT linked with Teamcity to do your builds, and Youtrack is linked to Teamcity, can you get this level of traceability?

Comment: There is youtrack 4.X documentation for this area, although it doesnt answer the end to end tracability concerns you have: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD4/Executing+Commands+from+Comment+to+VCS+Commit

Comment: Ah couldn't find them when searching the documentation, thanks. Good to see there is actually functionality to pass comments through to YouTrack. So the rest of the question pertaining to the viewing of a commit in Git from YouTrack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would rather someone else added to this, so I wont mark it as the answer as of yet but as I can see this being an attractive thing for a lot of development teams I will post my current findings.

I have managed to get **GIT talking to TeamCity** which in turn **talks to YouTrack**. So when I commit I can put comments over to the Youtrack items as well as move them around the board. If I then look into the TeamCity changes for a ticket in YouTrack I can then see the trace back through to the commit level to see who changed what and when, as well as the diffs between the versions so its a complete end to end solution.

One thing that tripped me up was **you NEED Teamcity users which have correct VCS usernames** bound, otherwise your changes wont be passed through to YouTrack.

Comment: Has anyone found the REST API to manually add a commit to a You Track issue? It would be simple enough to add a post commit hook, parse it, check the tags, branch or commit then attach it to YT. But I can't find the YT API for commits.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell : I've been looking for the same thing. What I found: There's no "commit" object in YouTrack to add. When so configured the browser issues a XHR call to YouTrack, which queries TeamCity (or github/gitlab/bitbucket cloud) for commits associated with that ticket, and display them.